# How to put the get value from this firebase database and placed inside query

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I want to use user location to Query some Country class
I want to put like this
Query query = database.child ("Countries").child ("received user location");
 My database looks like

```
User--
        |--- username   David
        |--- UserLocation     florida
        |--- userid     jdjdkdkdidjdndjdidj
```

How to put UserLocation value inside the query

Comment: I want to Query from above method is it possible

Answer (score 0):

If you have already stored in your database the `useerName` or the `userId`, than you can query to find out the location of a particular user and than use it in your `Query` or `DatabaseReference`.

```
DatabaseReference ref = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("users").child(userId);

ValueEventListener eventListener = new ValueEventListener() {
    @Override
    public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
        String userLocation = (String) dataSnapshot.child("location").getValue();

        Query query = database.child("Countries").child(userLocation); //Do whatever you want with the query
    }

    @Override
    public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {}
};
ref.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(eventListener);
```

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

The query is in another class so can we do like 
Query location = mdatabase.child ("users").child (userid).equalTo ("UserLocation");
Then placing it on Query query = mdatabase.child ("countries").child (String.valueOf (location));

Because the query is in outer class and every time I try to use it it shows null pointer exception